# How to translate jointstate to tf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the procdure to translate joint state given as process_value to a TF message between joined links. Is this documented anywhere. Are there helper functions to take (process_value, process_value_dot) to twist..etc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83776/how-to-translate-jointstate-to-tf/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) should be what you are asking for, if I understand your question correctly. Using a URDF robot model uploaded to the parameter server and joint states it receives via a topic, it publishes tf. This [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20state%20publisher%20on%20your%20own%20robot#Running_as_a_ROS_node) explains how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-26**:
Still I do not think it should be that difficult to create a tf from a joint state if you know the control state and the links involved but maybe I am wrong on that point.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-26**:
Actually that isn't difficult. It's the standard ROS way. You could do that yourself, i.e. make a node that subscribes joint states and computes the robot's kinematics from that, but in that case you'd replicate the robot_state_publisher functionality.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-27**:
There use to be helper functions eg. Twist t = s.twist(q,qdot);  But I can not find them.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-27**:
I don't know about this one, but a good guess would be to look in the tf namespace; there are a couple.